# How do I use mapDispatchToProps in place of directly accessing the Redux store?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm having trouble figuring out why my React Native component isn't preforming dispatching any of the actions I've tried to connected to it. I believe I've correctly followed the [suggested approach](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) to defining `matchDispatchToProps` as an object, but none of the expected actions seem to be happening.

Everything works fine if I explicitly import `store`. For example

```
store.dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'})
```

works where the examples using just

```
increment
```

fails.

How do I correctly dispatch actions using `mapDispatchToProps` in place of directly accessing the Redux store?

---

In fact, I wonder why I would't just add something like

```
export const counterAPI = bindActionCreators(
    { increment, reset },
    store.dispatch
)
```

in my `store.ts` (no longer exporting anything else from there, except `store` for use by `Provider`) and change

```
import { increment, reset } from "../store"
// ...
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(DemoCounter)
```

in `DemoCounter.tsx` to just

```
import { counterAPI } from "../store"
// ...
export default connect(null)(DemoCounter)
```

That seems to be a lot simpler and to achieve exactly the right level of modularity.

---

**DemoCounter.tsx**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Button, Text } from 'native-base'
import {connect} from "react-redux"

import { increment, reset } from "../store"



export class DemoCounter extends Component {

    private timerID: number = 0
    private interval = 1000

    private startTimer(): void {
        clearInterval(this.timerID)
        this.timerID = setInterval(() => {
            increment // Does nothing
        }, this.interval)
    }

    componentDidMount(): void {
        this.startTimer()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button onPress={increment}> /* Does nothing */
                    <Text>Reset A</Text>
                </Button>
                <Button onPress={() => {reset(); this.startTimer()}}> /* How to combine action with other behaviors? */
                    <Text>Reset B</Text>
                </Button>
                <Button onPress={reset}> /* Does nothing */
                    <Text>Reset C</Text>
                </Button>
            </View>
        )
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = {
    increment,
    reset,
}
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(DemoCounter)
```

**store.ts**:

```
import {createStore} from "redux"


interface CounterState {
    count: number;
}

const initialState: CounterState = {count: 0}


export type CounterAction =
    | { type: 'INCREMENT' }
    | { type: 'RESET' }


export const increment = (): CounterAction  => ({ type: "INCREMENT" })
export const reset = (): CounterAction => ({ type: "RESET" })

const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action: CounterAction): CounterState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return {...state, count: state.count + 1}
        case "RESET":
            return {...state, count: 1}
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export const store = createStore(counterReducer)
```

**App.tsx**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { store } from "./store"
import PerspectiveCounter from "./components/PerspectiveCounter"



export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <DemoCounter />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm...

I have never done it like that, so I am not sure what the problem is...

How about trying to define it my way? ;)
At least as a temporary workaround.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        increment: () =>
            dispatch({ type: '"INCREMENT"'})
    }
}
```

Any calling `this.props.increment`, of course.

Comment: Indeed. See my [musings added](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57513488/revisions) to the OP. The recommended approach doesn't even result in the right kind of modularity, IMV.